# StackPanel.Children.Clear() does not work correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I have a problem when I delete the children of my `StackPanel`.

At the start my `StackPanel` is empty. I call a method to add 11 `TextBox` in it. I want to delete the 11 `TextBox` before call this method again. So I call my stackpanel :

```
myStackPanel.Children.Clear()
```

and it is working (try with debug point and count). There are no children in `StackPanel` but the method returns 22 `TextBox` after the second call.

What is wrong with that please ?

XAML :

```
<StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel"/>
```

WPF :

```
var count1 = myStackPanel.Children.Count; // 11 (first call give me 11)
myStackPanel.Children.Clear();
var count2 = myStackPanel.Children.Count; // 0 (it is working)
using (var selectAll = new Database1Entities())
{
    var querySelectAll =
        from myVariable
        in selectAll.Entrees
        select myVariable;
    foreach (var ligne in querySelectAll) // 11 (0 + 11 = 11 right ?)
    {
        TextBox myTextBoxNom = new TextBox();
        myTextBoxNom.Text = ligne.Nom;
        myStackPanel.Children.Add(myTextBoxNom);
    }
}
var count3 = myStackPanel.Children.Count; // EDIT >> 11 (but 22 on screen)
```

EDIT :: Works with tip in comment

Comment: Are you sure that querySelectAll has only 11 items?

Comment: Yeah sure.. It is weird..

Comment: Besides the part where you shouldn't be doing this, the behavior you see certainly is odd.

Comment: I agree with BradleyDotNET. Have you considered using DataBinding to a ViewModel instead?

Comment: Stop me if I am wrong but I did it in that way because I don't know the number of row in my database so I don't know an other way to create TextBox as need..

Comment: [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) dude, and I may be wrong without testing but this seems like a potential memory leak via subscription to the ValueChanged event using a strong reference chain to keep track of your children.count.

Comment: There must be more 11 items, there's no other explanation.

Comment: @Cozen, I'm not clear on your edit - is count3 == 11 but you see 22 text boxes?

Comment: Tested your code (just without the database access) and it works fine. I agree with what was said before, read about MVVM and use `ItemsControl` with data binding. Then you won't have to worry about this anymore.

Comment: I will try the ItemsControl even if i  am not a pro to manage this. However I assure you that I have a problem with the code after call 2 time my method.. It's not a problem on the number of elements It's a problem of display.

Comment: If you continue to program WPF as if it were Windows Forms, you will be in for a tough ride... use MVVM and use the advantages of WPF.

Comment: It is hard to learn at home with google sources sometimes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a solution for this bug however I used the DataBinding to avoid it like you can read in the comments.

Comment: Pray tell, what is the solution? If Google leads someone here they will find no answer. It will make them sad. The tick is a lie.

Comment: Sadly, I never found the solution... I just worked on an other way to do it.

Comment: Would you say this is a candidate for `answered` status? I wouldn't. Please share the workaround.

Comment: Yes, how can I give this status ?

Comment: This question was asked 9 months ago. I just can tell you that I found an other way to do my stuff but my project is over since a long time and to be honest I do not have the source code (hdd reset).

Comment: The green tick does not represent *solved* - it is not a *closed* flag. It is an *answered* flag. This question is not answered as there is no viewable answer, and should not have the tick. This question is a community resource, browsable by thousands of programmers! Please delete this answer if you have no intention of providing an answer.